# Hibernate Core upgrade from version 6.1.7 to 6.2.2 causes DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `Spring Boot` version `3.0.13` with my REST API and everything is working fine when I save example data into my database. However, when I upgrade to `Spring Boot` version `3.1.0`, loading my example data breaks with the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute batch [Batch entry 1 insert into deck_card (card_id,rarity,id) values (1,1,2) was aborted: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "deck_card_card_id_key"
  Detail: Key (card_id)=(1) already exists.  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.] [insert into deck_card (card_id,rarity,id) values (?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into deck_card (card_id,rarity,id) values (?,?,?)]; constraint [deck_card_card_id_key]
```

I noticed `hibernate-core` was updated from version `6.1.7` to `6.2.2` alongside it which is responsible for the issue.

[image]

Is there any known behavior change from `Hibernate` which might be related to the `DataIntegrityViolationException`? I don't understand why this worked fine with the previous version, so it doesn't seem like my code is broken. Instead of working out a minimial reproducible example, maybe someone or some website can point me in the right direction on what I should know about the newer `Hibernate` version regarding this.